# Ionic 2 - Http POST body parameters not being sent

Tags: http, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 Beta 11. I am trying to send a request to an external API which will return a JSON response. I have overcome CORS issues and I am communicating with the API however **I can not send the body information** that is required. I have tried formatting the body variable in the following ways, each with no success:

As an object: `{email: this.email, password: this.password}`

As a stringified object: `JSON.stringify({email: this.email, password: this.password})`

As a string: `'email=' + this.email + '&password=' + this.password`

Here is my code:

```
import {Component}                                      from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, MenuController}                  from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions}                  from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
  nav: NavController;    
  username: string;
  password: string;

  constructor(nav: NavController, private http: Http) {
    this.nav = nav;
  }

  doLogin() {
    let body = JSON.stringify({
      email: this.username,
      password: this.password });
    let headers = new Headers({
      'NDAPI-Key': 'XXXXXXXXXX',
      'NDAPI-Host': 'XXXXXXXXXXX' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    this.http
        .post('/api', body, options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            data => {
              console.log(data);
            },
            err => {
              console.log("ERROR!: ", err);
            }
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: please, help me out. How did you overcome CORS issues. I'm stuck there.

Comment: The files that you are having trouble accessing (because of CORS), do you have access to the server that they are hosted on? If so, you may be able to enable CORS on that server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just discovered the solution to my problem. I was trying to send some data of type X to the server while telling the server that I was sending data of type Y. I'm still a little confused as to the data types that I was sending however I have been able to resolve my issues by using the following code:

```
import {Component}                                      from '@angular/core';
import {NavController}                                  from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions}                  from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
  nav: NavController;

  username: string;
  password: string;

  constructor(nav: NavController, private http: Http) {
    this.nav = nav;
  }

  doLogin() {
    let body = new FormData();
    body.append('email', this.username);
    body.append('password', this.password);
    let headers = new Headers({
      'NDAPI-Key': 'XXXXXXXXX',
      'NDAPI-Host': 'XXXXXXXXX' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    this.http
        .post('/api', body, options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            data => {
              console.log(data);
            },
            err => {
              console.log("ERROR!: ", err);
            }
        );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I am new to Ionic 2 but after long search Form data option worked for me like below

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let body = new FormData();
    body.append('username', username);
    body.append('password', password);
    console.log(body);
    console.log(headers);
    return this.http.post('http://api/v1/get_user',body,headers).map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem that my parameters were not posted to my PHP Server. I changed parameters to raw format (shown in my body variable), and it started working. See sample code below.

```
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers
    });
    // TODO: Encode the values using encodeURIComponent().
    let body = 'email=' + email + '&password=' + password;
```

Comment: It's worth explaining why you think your answer will work - the OP might not understand what you've done.

Answer (score 2):

Angular2 Ionic 2 HTTP Post Method

```
import {Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {


constructor(public http:Http) { }


postCall()
{
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
let data=JSON.stringify({username:"raja"});
this.http.post('http://localhost/ionic/postResponse.php',data,headers)
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(res => {
alert("success "+res);
}, (err) => {
alert("failed");
});
}


}
```

For more info visit https://ampersandacademy.com/tutorials/ionic-framework-version-2/send-data-and-receive-data-in-the-ionic-2-framework-using-angular2-http-post-method